# нужен аналог pyautogui

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, pyautogui

pyautogui никак не хочет выводить текст на русском языке от метода pyautogui.write(). посмотрел, что pyautogui не воспринимает русский текст.

Можете ли вы посоветовать подходящий аналог с присутствующими методами написания(write) + прожимания какой-либо кнопки(press). слышал про pywinauto, pywin32, но в документации не нашел функций, похожих на данные.

Comment: Если напишете, куда и как вам нужно выводить русский текст, то быстрее получите ответ, так как не все знакомы с библиотекой `pyautogui` и её функцией `write`.

Comment: Можете использовать ```keyboard```

Answer (score 0):

pynput(https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)
Думаю это более подходящий аналог pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать keyboard.
`pip install keyboard`

```
import keyboard
keyboard.write('привет мир!!')
```